# How to perform a Like type query using WhereParameters and EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entitydatasource

In the code-behind I want to apply a dynamic where clause for the entitydatasource, but I want this where to be like and not equal.  I have this code working which is equal I want an equivalence code that somehow translates this into a Like statement.

```
EntityDataSource1.WhereParameters.Add("Name", TypeCode.String, tbxSearch.Text);
```

Solution after reading Jupaol comment :

Xaml:

```
<WhereParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbxSearch" Name="Name" Type="String" />
</WhereParameters>
```

Code Behind: (on load event)

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxSearch.Text))
{
   this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "1=1";  //fetch all data if empty
}
else
{
   this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.Name like '%' + @Name + '%'"; //filter
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that code you are only adding a parameter, the place where you need to define your *like* comparison, is in the where clause

The code you posted can be translated into:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="eds"
        .....
        Where="it.fname like '%' + @Name + '%'"
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbxSearch" Name="Name" DefaultValue="" />
        </WhereParameters>
```

To Add the where in code behind:

```
this.eds.Where = "it.fname like '%' + @Name + '%'";
```

**Edit1:**

For some reason, if I place the parameter declaration like yours (in code), it is not working, however if I place the parameter in the markup like this:

```
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbxSearch" Name="Name" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
        </WhereParameters>
```

And in `Page_Load`

```
this.eds.Where = "it.fname like '%' + @Name + '%'";
```

It works

Comment: well i want to do it in the code behind... since i need to filter the datasource on a certain event...

Comment: Applies the same logic, since the `Where` property is a `string` you can assign the where criteria in the code behind, Check my updated response

Comment: i got this error: The query syntax is not valid. Near identifier 'abcd'

Comment: I just tested, it is working, remember that you should replace `fname` in the above code for your field. It should look like `it.YourField`

Comment: btw do i need to add anything in the xaml? like where parameter or something? i have this in the code behind.
this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.Name like '%'" + tbxSearch.Text + "'%'";

hmmm :(